# How to group same factors in plotted bar chart

Tags: r, dplyr, r-highcharter

Trying to get the grouped factors to plot beside each other in clusters e.g. all 'lows' for each year together, all 'mediums' for each year together etc. and use legend to colour years. Dplyr grouping not grouping by Type as in group_by(Type) and group_by(Year) returns the same dataframe. What am I missing?

```
# create dataframe
year <- 2020
low <- 45
medium <- 52
high <- 98
df <- data.frame(year, low, medium, high)

year <- 2021
low <- 60
medium <- 83
high <- 80
df2 <- data.frame(year, low, medium, high)

year <- 2022
low <- 64
medium <- 34
high <- 20
df3 <- data.frame(year, low, medium, high)

year <- 2023
low <- 62
medium <- 47
high <- 58
df4 <- data.frame(year, low, medium, high)

test <- rbind(df, df2, df3, df4)
test <- test %>% pivot_longer(!year, names_to="Type", values_to = "total")

library(highcharter)

highchart() %>%


hc_chart(type = "column") %>%
  hc_add_series(name = "Type" , data = test$total , color ="green" )%>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = test$Type)%>% 
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Type"))%>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "GWh"))%>%
  hc_title(text= "Types Year Comparison") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text= "test") %>% 
  hc_caption(text= "Based on year 2007 population")%>% 
  hc_legend(enabled= FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Type` as factors and `year` as character:

```
# Original data
test <- tibble::tribble(
  ~year,    ~Type, ~total,
  2020,    "low",     45,
  2020, "medium",     52,
  2020,   "high",     98,
  2021,    "low",     60,
  2021, "medium",     83,
  2021,   "high",     80,
  2022,    "low",     64,
  2022, "medium",     34,
  2022,   "high",     20,
  2023,    "low",     62,
  2023, "medium",     47,
  2023,   "high",     58)

# Adjust type and year
test <- mutate(test, Type = fct(Type), year = as.character(year)) 

# The plot
test %>% 
  hchart("column", hcaes(x = Type, y = total, group = year)) %>% 
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "GWh"))%>%
  hc_title(text= "Types Year Comparison") %>% 
  hc_subtitle(text= "test") %>% 
  hc_caption(text= "Based on year 2007 population")%>% 
  hc_legend(enabled= FALSE)
```

The plot output:
[image]

**Edit**. Maybe consider `hc_legend(enabled = TRUE)`:

[image]

Comment: Great thank you, worked perfectly. Tibble::Tribble so useful

Comment: @Magnetar check the `datapasta::tribble_paste` to copy tibbles and data frames in tribble format!